# Is there any image editing software that can open Microsoft DirectDraw Surface files in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, image-processing, image-editor

I need an editor that can open, save and edit Microsoft DirectDraw Surface (`.dds`) files. I know Paint.NET can open them, but well, it's .NET, so...

GIMP doesn't seem to open them and I can't find a plug-in that works.

Note, I've tried `sudo apt-get install gimp-dds`, I get this error:

```
Opening '/home/_____/Desktop/explorer/InjectPack/OutDDS/176.dds' failed:
Procedure 'file-dds-load' returned no return values
```

I'll accept anything that works. Thanks!

Comment: .dds is an extension, what is their mimetype? What kind of files are them?

Comment: They're extracted from a game, and I'm trying to edit them. They're basically game textures.

Comment: Interesting, test imagemagick from my answer and if this does not work it would be nice to see some of your dds files...

Comment: @dadexix86: i assume it is [DirectDraw Surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectDraw_Surface)...?

Comment: Yeah it's DirectDraw Surface, sorry about not addressing that.

Comment: @DJCrashdummy maybe, or maybe are some other file with just extension .dds... Without having more informations, it is only a wild guess :) EDIT: now that we know that it is DirectDraw Surface, it is not a guess anymore :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The good news is that the command line application  ImageMagick can read, write and edit DDS (Microsoft Direct Draw Surface) files. Test your own copy of ImageMagick as follows:

```
andrew@ilium~$ identify -list format | grep 'Microsoft DirectDraw Surface'
      DDS* rw+   Microsoft DirectDraw Surface
     DXT1* rw+   Microsoft DirectDraw Surface
     DXT5* rw+   Microsoft DirectDraw Surface
andrew@ilium~$
```

The codes after DDS,DXT1 and DXT5 signify:

```
* native blob support
r read support
w write support
+ support for multiple images
```

And certainly on my system ImageMagick's `convert` utility easily produced the required DDS files and successfully converted DDS files to other formats such as jpg and png...

Comment: Perfect, even has the formats I need. Testing now.

Comment: My fingers are crossed :)

Comment: Works! Thank you! (Sorry for taking so long, was having some issues)

Answer (score 3):

### 2019 Answer

Gimp 2.10 now supports DDS out of the box.

Comment: Time moves on :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried XnViewMP? It's known to work on some dds files, but some read errors have been reported too. You can't find it in official repositories, but here: http://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/#downloads. Don't worry, it's free, paid version is for Windows only.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use this if I ever run into issues with ImageMagick but it probably won't happen